# Assign a variable a different value if it is '0' without using if else

Tags: php, variables

I have 3 variables like this

```
$posted_on = '0';
$shared_on = '34';
$by_id = '12';
```

I want to assign `$owner` a value from the above the 3 variables whose value is not `0` starting with `$posted_on`.
Currently I am doing this, but this doesn't print the correct results

```
$owner = $posted_on;
$owner = '0' ? $shared_on : $owner;
$owner = '0' ? $by_id : $owner;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mixed up your operators. To do a comparison, you need to use `==` or `===`.

```
$owner = $posted_on;
$owner == 0 ? $shared_on : $owner;
$owner == '0' ? $by_id : $owner;
```

By using the `=` (assignment) operator, you effectively are assigning `0` to `$owner` for each statement and then checking if the result (which is always `0`, by the definition of assignment) is true.

> The difference between the two is that '==' should be used to check if the values of the two operands are equal or not. On the other hand, '===' checks the values as well as the type of operands.

(http://www.geeksww.com/tutorials/web_development/php_hypertext_preprocessor/tips_and_tricks/difference_between_equal_and_identical_comparison_operators_php.php)

You can also use the `?:` operator, which will check the left-hand side for a true value (for numbers, any non-zero) and use the right-hand side only if the left-hand side is false:

```
$owner = $posted_on ?: ($shared_on ?: $by_id);
```

To write cleaner code in this case, however, I would just use the if statements. This is because you don't need to reassign `$owner` to itself in the false conditions like you do in the example.

Comment: I downvoted because your original suggestion `$owner == 0 ? $shared_on : $owner;` replaces one mistake with another, this statement actually does nothing. OP did not really *mix up* operators, he just forgot to specify what should be compared to `'0'`

Answer (score 1):

A single `=` assigns a value, a double `==` or tripple `===` evaluates two variables.

Try this:

```
$owner = $posted_on;
$owner = $owner === 0 ? $shared_on : $owner;
$owner = $owner === '0' ? $by_id : $owner;
```

Comment: @OP: keep in mind that the tripple equation sign also checks for type identity. It seems you are having strings and integers alike, so I'd recommend using `==`.

Comment: @acme I understood from the original question that he wants to assign different variables if the value is `0` or `'0'`, which is why I used the triple equation sign.

Comment: NP, it was not really clear in the original post. In the meantime he edited his post accordingly ;-)

Comment: This isn't a syntax error -- the code compiles and runs, just not as expected.

Comment: I didn't mean syntax error in terms of the code not running, but that he had a typo causing it not to run as expected.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the behaviour of `or` and implicit type conversion:

```
$a = 1; $b = 0; $c = 5;
$x = $a or $x = $b or $x = $c;

echo $x;
```

Comment: -1 This might be a clever use of short circuit evaluation but it also destroys the readability of code intent.

Comment: Read it out aloud: "x is a or x is b or x is c", my thinking process on encountering this would be "x is one of a,b or c, -> the first one which is not false"

Answer (score 1):

The shortest way would be:

```
$owner = $posted_on ?: ($shared_on ?: $by_id);
```

The [short ternary operator](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary) `?:` evaluates to the left argument if it is `true`-ish (which any non-zero number is), otherwise to the right argument.

Note that the parentheses are necessary because in PHP the ternary operator is [left associative](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php)

Comment: The link here for short ternary operator does not actually call the `?:` operator "short ternary." fab's name is correct, but just a warning for future readers not to search the link for that text.

Comment: Thanks for the addition. I added an anchor to the link to reduce search effort :)

Comment: Even better! I was going to do it for you but I couldn't find the anchor.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a one-liner:

```
$owner = $posted_on == '0' ? ($shared_on == '0' ? $shared_on : $by_id) : $posted_on;
```

Or, if dealing with numeric values,

```
$owner = $posted_on ?: ($shared_on ?: $by_id);
```

Comment: -1 Sorry, but I think this looks messier. Of course, I'd just add simple if statements here.

Comment: @DavidPfeffer It's not messy at all - and it's faster, too.  Of course, it's a matter of preference whether to use single-line syntax.

Comment: @RayZ `$owner` will have `$by_id` value if both `$posted_on` and `$shared_on` are 0.